# DKIM Fails (body hash) when signing at MTA using opendkim

Tags: php, phpmailer, postfix-mta, dkim, phplist

We are running into trouble with signing our outgoing mailings with DKIM using opendkim as a filter for Postfix.

This issue only occurs when sending HTML emails from phpList. All other text mailings and mailings from other services sign correctly and verify.  phpList uses phpMailer as the engine.

If we send the mailing as "text", then we have no problem. If we send the mailing as "HTML" then body hash fails.

This problem existed in v2, however we used to force phpList to ONLY send as HTML.

This error occurs when sending the message as a joint HTML and TEXT email (which is the default in v3).

I presume it's something to do with line breaks/returns.

Can somebody point us in the right direction?

Thanks for your help in advance.

**Port25 verifier service - a message that passes DKIM (Text only)**

```
==========================================================
Summary of Results
==========================================================
SPF check:          pass
DomainKeys check:   neutral
DKIM check:         pass
Sender-ID check:    pass
SpamAssassin check: ham

==========================================================
Details:
==========================================================


----------------------------------------------------------
DomainKeys check details:
----------------------------------------------------------
Result:         neutral (message not signed)
ID(s) verified: header.From=updates@flyawaysimulation.com
DNS record(s):

----------------------------------------------------------
DKIM check details:
----------------------------------------------------------
Result:         pass (matches From: updates@flyawaysimulation.com)
ID(s) verified: header.d=flyawaysimulation.com
Canonicalized Headers:
    to:check-auth-ryan=rbftpnetworks.com@verifier.port25.com'0D''0A'
    subject:Test'20'123'0D''0A'
    date:Thu,'20'18'20'Sep'20'2014'20'21:50:35'20'+0100'0D''0A'
    from:Fly'20'Away'20'Simulation'20'<updates@flyawaysimulation.com>'0D''0A'
    reply-to:Fly'20'Away'20'Simulation'20'<updates@flyawaysimulation.com>'0D''0A'
    list-help:<https://flyawaysimulation.com/lists/?p=preferences&uid=1e629246241f8e9714134ee8076ad406>'0D''0A'
    list-unsubscribe:<https://flyawaysimulation.com/lists/?p=unsubscribe&uid=1e629246241f8e9714134ee8076ad406&jo=1>'0D''0A'
    list-subscribe:<https://flyawaysimulation.com/lists/?p=subscribe>'0D''0A'
    list-owner:<mailto:abuse@flyawaysimulation.com>'0D''0A'
    dkim-signature:v=1;'20'a=rsa-sha256;'20'c=relaxed/simple;'20'd=flyawaysimulation.com;'20's=mail;'20't=1411073436;'20'bh=hhSjWh2jttCh3y1SOIZzUVlxN+KYTuNZ+eh16bzchHc=;'20'h=To:Subject:Date:From:Reply-To:List-Help:List-Unsubscribe:'20'List-Subscribe:List-Owner;'20'b=

Canonicalized Body:
    '20'test'20'123'0D''0A'
    '0D''0A'
    '0D''0A'
    '0D''0A'
    '20''20''0D''0A'


DNS record(s):
    mail._domainkey.flyawaysimulation.com. 3600 IN TXT "v=DKIM1;p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDimrx9MV1sFyUCVPeH6SFMBy7Cb2AU6aB9i3GazP7QKWG5pWWkFEurFImNbwi4wKz6dtKQeEkcGzPdzyeD+hXaSG2sl86T4pnwIxUaBMlW+FWfaNx0XPphacPAYjtkJGVoZGmmIbK3tH8HLZqdCEy6YIKd0kNSXQqFEMQseHaR6wIDAQAB"

Public key used for verification: mail._domainkey.flyawaysimulation.com (1024 bits)

NOTE: DKIM checking has been performed based on the latest DKIM specs
(RFC 4871 or draft-ietf-dkim-base-10) and verification may fail for
older versions.  If you are using Port25's PowerMTA, you need to use
version 3.2r11 or later to get a compatible version of DKIM.



==========================================================
Original Email
==========================================================

Return-Path: <updates@flyawaysimulation.com>
Received: from web3.rbftpnetworks.net (195.224.144.101) by verifier.port25.com id h3d2q211u9cu for <check-auth-ryan=rbftpnetworks.com@verifier.port25.com>; Thu, 18 Sep 2014 16:50:41 -0400 (envelope-from <updates@flyawaysimulation.com>)
Authentication-Results: verifier.port25.com; spf=pass smtp.mailfrom=updates@flyawaysimulation.com
Authentication-Results: verifier.port25.com; domainkeys=neutral (message not signed) header.From=updates@flyawaysimulation.com
Authentication-Results: verifier.port25.com; dkim=pass (matches From: updates@flyawaysimulation.com) header.d=flyawaysimulation.com
Authentication-Results: verifier.port25.com; sender-id=pass header.From=updates@flyawaysimulation.com
Received: by web3.rbftpnetworks.net (Postfix, from userid 70)
    id 2FF6D3E2B4BC; Thu, 18 Sep 2014 21:50:35 +0100 (BST)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/simple;
    d=flyawaysimulation.com; s=mail; t=1411073436;
    bh=hhSjWh2jttCh3y1SOIZzUVlxN+KYTuNZ+eh16bzchHc=;
    h=To:Subject:Date:From:Reply-To:List-Help:List-Unsubscribe:
     List-Subscribe:List-Owner;
    b=kz3pyKnsxvzKKc9I764d8xwTxMQkJNcdHSup9+BOoNujSXTOyyAM1tpc5QWIhGMa4
     NOwsePDv5qfladW3kAh7TuwWW9geH6gdV9PhHF5RCg6jyHHbUY8t4mpIcW7w4yNuIK
     BMMbXk4+puGpEKdyRgfGKXxYjI0bVKK1Ck2vdb5Q=
To: check-auth-ryan=rbftpnetworks.com@verifier.port25.com
Subject: Test 123
Received: from host81-138-131-190.in-addr.btopenworld.com [81.138.131.190] by flyawaysimulation.com with HTTP; Thu, 18 Sep 2014 21:50:35 +0100
Date: Thu, 18 Sep 2014 21:50:35 +0100
From: Fly Away Simulation <updates@flyawaysimulation.com>
Reply-To: Fly Away Simulation <updates@flyawaysimulation.com>
Message-ID: <535768d2df1f49b5df91d9b010abeba9@flyawaysimulation.com>
X-Priority: 3
X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.5 (https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer/)
X-phpList-version: 3.0.7
X-MessageID: 8
X-ListMember: check-auth-ryan=rbftpnetworks.com@verifier.port25.com
Precedence: bulk
Bounces-To: updates@flyawaysimulation.com
List-Help: <https://flyawaysimulation.com/lists/?p=preferences&uid=1e629246241f8e9714134ee8076ad406>
List-Unsubscribe: <https://flyawaysimulation.com/lists/?p=unsubscribe&uid=1e629246241f8e9714134ee8076ad406&jo=1>
List-Subscribe: <https://flyawaysimulation.com/lists/?p=subscribe>
List-Owner: <mailto:abuse@flyawaysimulation.com>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8

 test 123
```

**Port25 verifier service - a message that fails DKIM (Text/HTML email)**

```
==========================================================
Summary of Results
==========================================================
SPF check:          pass
DomainKeys check:   neutral
DKIM check:         fail
Sender-ID check:    pass
SpamAssassin check: ham

==========================================================
Details:
==========================================================


----------------------------------------------------------
DKIM check details:
----------------------------------------------------------
Result:         fail (wrong body hash: expected nb2kCq5nNBE+IfyLiAIH9t/9x7Kk5PpCb+1GdO/wiJ8=)
ID(s) verified: 
Canonicalized Headers:
    to:check-auth-ryan=rbftpnetworks.com@verifier.port25.com'0D''0A'
    subject:Test'20'123'0D''0A'
    date:Thu,'20'18'20'Sep'20'2014'20'21:52:19'20'+0100'0D''0A'
    from:Fly'20'Away'20'Simulation'20'<updates@flyawaysimulation.com>'0D''0A'
    reply-to:Fly'20'Away'20'Simulation'20'<updates@flyawaysimulation.com>'0D''0A'
    list-help:<https://flyawaysimulation.com/lists/?p=preferences&uid=1e629246241f8e9714134ee8076ad406>'0D''0A'
    list-unsubscribe:<https://flyawaysimulation.com/lists/?p=unsubscribe&uid=1e629246241f8e9714134ee8076ad406&jo=1>'0D''0A'
    list-subscribe:<https://flyawaysimulation.com/lists/?p=subscribe>'0D''0A'
    list-owner:<mailto:abuse@flyawaysimulation.com>'0D''0A'
    dkim-signature:v=1;'20'a=rsa-sha256;'20'c=relaxed/simple;'20'd=flyawaysimulation.com;'20's=mail;'20't=1411073540;'20'bh=XMTdnEvx/N4aZB10KoQqWOQW+MUVFvU66kqiSqm0XKc=;'20'h=To:Subject:Date:From:Reply-To:List-Help:List-Unsubscribe:'20'List-Subscribe:List-Owner;'20'b=

Canonicalized Body:
    --b1_b4a02db1226bc348457a47d51e902619'0D''0A'
    Content-Type:'20'text/plain;'20'charset=UTF-8'0D''0A'
    Content-Transfer-Encoding:'20'quoted-printable'0D''0A'
    '0D''0A'
    '20'test'20'123'0D''0A'
    '0D''0A'
    '0D''0A'
    '0D''0A'
    '0D''0A'
    '0D''0A'
    '0D''0A'
    '0D''0A'
    '20'=20'0D''0A'
    '0D''0A'
    '0D''0A'
    '0D''0A'
    --b1_b4a02db1226bc348457a47d51e902619'0D''0A'
    Content-Type:'20'text/html;'20'charset=UTF-8'0D''0A'
    Content-Transfer-Encoding:'20'quoted-printable'0D''0A'
    '0D''0A'
    <html><head>=0A'20''20''20''20''20''20''20''20'<meta'20'content=3D"text/html;charset=3DUTF-8"'20'http-equ='0D''0A'
    '0D''0A'
    iv=3D"Content-Type">=0A'20''20''20''20''20''20''20''20'<title></title></head><body><p>&nbsp;test'20'12='0D''0A'
    '0D''0A'
    3</p>=0A<img'20'src=3D"https://flyawaysimulation.com/lists/ut.php?u=3D1e629246='0D''0A'
    '0D''0A'
    241f8e9714134ee8076ad406&amp;m=3D8"'20'width=3D"1"'20'height=3D"1"'20'border=3D"0"'20'/='0D''0A'
    '0D''0A'
    ></body></html>'0D''0A'
    '0D''0A'
    '0D''0A'
    --b1_b4a02db1226bc348457a47d51e902619--'0D''0A'


DNS record(s):

NOTE: DKIM checking has been performed based on the latest DKIM specs
(RFC 4871 or draft-ietf-dkim-base-10) and verification may fail for
older versions.  If you are using Port25's PowerMTA, you need to use
version 3.2r11 or later to get a compatible version of DKIM.


==========================================================
Original Email
==========================================================

Return-Path: <updates@flyawaysimulation.com>
Received: from web3.rbftpnetworks.net (195.224.144.101) by verifier.port25.com id h3d30c11u9cb for <check-auth-ryan=rbftpnetworks.com@verifier.port25.com>; Thu, 18 Sep 2014 16:52:22 -0400 (envelope-from <updates@flyawaysimulation.com>)
Authentication-Results: verifier.port25.com; spf=pass smtp.mailfrom=updates@flyawaysimulation.com
Authentication-Results: verifier.port25.com; domainkeys=neutral (message not signed) header.From=updates@flyawaysimulation.com
Authentication-Results: verifier.port25.com; dkim=fail (wrong body hash: expected nb2kCq5nNBE+IfyLiAIH9t/9x7Kk5PpCb+1GdO/wiJ8=) 
Authentication-Results: verifier.port25.com; sender-id=pass header.From=updates@flyawaysimulation.com
Received: by web3.rbftpnetworks.net (Postfix, from userid 70)
    id 014C83E2B53F; Thu, 18 Sep 2014 21:52:19 +0100 (BST)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/simple;
    d=flyawaysimulation.com; s=mail; t=1411073540;
    bh=XMTdnEvx/N4aZB10KoQqWOQW+MUVFvU66kqiSqm0XKc=;
    h=To:Subject:Date:From:Reply-To:List-Help:List-Unsubscribe:
     List-Subscribe:List-Owner;
    b=OXitjsekFORKng9NPtJ7GSrKROUf+EGj/zetZ7ZoXWGeZerr2+IUNFgSZcNPjub5M
     VazJtwOMRZ5g7r6SrUWjPfkpDH6nt3qecOW2E000ftsWwv78wPtD4mc0OIN/IsY52h
     vk+mbHrQb4ToUHmxIGRIfB/NOdDiXG7Gp+aVrgRY=
To: check-auth-ryan=rbftpnetworks.com@verifier.port25.com
Subject: Test 123
Received: from host81-138-131-190.in-addr.btopenworld.com [81.138.131.190] by flyawaysimulation.com with HTTP; Thu, 18 Sep 2014 21:52:19 +0100
Date: Thu, 18 Sep 2014 21:52:19 +0100
From: Fly Away Simulation <updates@flyawaysimulation.com>
Reply-To: Fly Away Simulation <updates@flyawaysimulation.com>
Message-ID: <b4a02db1226bc348457a47d51e902619@flyawaysimulation.com>
X-Priority: 3
X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.5 (https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer/)
X-phpList-version: 3.0.7
X-MessageID: 8
X-ListMember: check-auth-ryan=rbftpnetworks.com@verifier.port25.com
Precedence: bulk
Bounces-To: updates@flyawaysimulation.com
List-Help: <https://flyawaysimulation.com/lists/?p=preferences&uid=1e629246241f8e9714134ee8076ad406>
List-Unsubscribe: <https://flyawaysimulation.com/lists/?p=unsubscribe&uid=1e629246241f8e9714134ee8076ad406&jo=1>
List-Subscribe: <https://flyawaysimulation.com/lists/?p=subscribe>
List-Owner: <mailto:abuse@flyawaysimulation.com>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="b1_b4a02db1226bc348457a47d51e902619"

--b1_b4a02db1226bc348457a47d51e902619
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

 test 123







 =20



--b1_b4a02db1226bc348457a47d51e902619
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<html><head>=0A        <meta content=3D"text/html;charset=3DUTF-8" http-equ=

iv=3D"Content-Type">=0A        <title></title></head><body><p>&nbsp;test 12=

3</p>=0A<img src=3D"https://flyawaysimulation.com/lists/ut.php?u=3D1e629246=

241f8e9714134ee8076ad406&amp;m=3D8" width=3D"1" height=3D"1" border=3D"0" /=

> </body></html>


--b1_b4a02db1226bc348457a47d51e902619--
```

phpMailer version 5.2.5 (packaged with phpList)

**UPDATE:**
We can pass the DKIM verification check on Port25's tester if we enable **"FixCRLF yes"** in the opendkim config.  However, this still **FAILS** Gmail DKIM verification.

**Test output of passed message with "FixCRLF yes":**

```
==========================================================
Summary of Results
==========================================================
SPF check:          pass
DomainKeys check:   neutral
DKIM check:         pass
Sender-ID check:    pass
SpamAssassin check: ham


----------------------------------------------------------
DomainKeys check details:
----------------------------------------------------------
Result:         neutral (message not signed)
ID(s) verified: header.From=updates@flyawaysimulation.com
DNS record(s):

----------------------------------------------------------
DKIM check details:
----------------------------------------------------------
Result:         pass (matches From: updates@flyawaysimulation.com)
ID(s) verified: header.d=flyawaysimulation.com
Canonicalized Headers:
    to:check-auth-ryan=rbftpnetworks.com@verifier.port25.com'0D''0A'
    subject:Test'20'123'0D''0A'
    date:Sun,'20'21'20'Sep'20'2014'20'15:57:46'20'+0100'0D''0A'
    from:Fly'20'Away'20'Simulation'20'<updates@flyawaysimulation.com>'0D''0A'
    reply-to:Fly'20'Away'20'Simulation'20'<updates@flyawaysimulation.com>'0D''0A'
    list-help:<https://flyawaysimulation.com/lists/?p=preferences&uid=1e629246241f8e9714134ee8076ad406>'0D''0A'
    list-unsubscribe:<https://flyawaysimulation.com/lists/?p=unsubscribe&uid=1e629246241f8e9714134ee8076ad406&jo=1>'0D''0A'
    list-subscribe:<https://flyawaysimulation.com/lists/?p=subscribe>'0D''0A'
    list-owner:<mailto:abuse@flyawaysimulation.com>'0D''0A'
    dkim-signature:v=1;'20'a=rsa-sha256;'20'c=relaxed/simple;'20'd=flyawaysimulation.com;'20's=mail;'20't=1411311466;'20'bh=PUR9ib4HOSSj9G3jmXSCyzc1LAtqQeyWPSAii67TLd8=;'20'h=To:Subject:Date:From:Reply-To:List-Help:List-Unsubscribe:'20'List-Subscribe:List-Owner;'20'b=

Canonicalized Body:
    --b1_4ecb49f93b720bc688fe3bcdcafed5b0'0D''0A'
    Content-Type:'20'text/plain;'20'charset=UTF-8'0D''0A'
    Content-Transfer-Encoding:'20'quoted-printable'0D''0A'
    '0D''0A'
    '20'test'20'123'0D''0A'
    '0D''0A'
    '0D''0A'
    '0D''0A'
    '0D''0A'
    '0D''0A'
    '0D''0A'
    '0D''0A'
    '20'=20'0D''0A'
    '0D''0A'
    '0D''0A'
    '0D''0A'
    --b1_4ecb49f93b720bc688fe3bcdcafed5b0'0D''0A'
    Content-Type:'20'text/html;'20'charset=UTF-8'0D''0A'
    Content-Transfer-Encoding:'20'quoted-printable'0D''0A'
    '0D''0A'
    <html><head>=0A'20''20''20''20''20''20''20''20'<meta'20'content=3D"text/html;charset=3DUTF-8"'20'http-equ='0D''0A'
    '0D''0A'
    iv=3D"Content-Type">=0A'20''20''20''20''20''20''20''20'<title></title></head><body><p>&nbsp;test'20'12='0D''0A'
    '0D''0A'
    3</p>=0A<img'20'src=3D"https://flyawaysimulation.com/lists/ut.php?u=3D1e629246='0D''0A'
    '0D''0A'
    241f8e9714134ee8076ad406&amp;m=3D8"'20'width=3D"1"'20'height=3D"1"'20'border=3D"0"'20'/='0D''0A'
    '0D''0A'
    ></body></html>'0D''0A'
    '0D''0A'
    '0D''0A'
    --b1_4ecb49f93b720bc688fe3bcdcafed5b0--'0D''0A'


DNS record(s):
    mail._domainkey.flyawaysimulation.com. 3600 IN TXT "v=DKIM1;p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDimrx9MV1sFyUCVPeH6SFMBy7Cb2AU6aB9i3GazP7QKWG5pWWkFEurFImNbwi4wKz6dtKQeEkcGzPdzyeD+hXaSG2sl86T4pnwIxUaBMlW+FWfaNx0XPphacPAYjtkJGVoZGmmIbK3tH8HLZqdCEy6YIKd0kNSXQqFEMQseHaR6wIDAQAB"

Public key used for verification: mail._domainkey.flyawaysimulation.com (1024 bits)

NOTE: DKIM checking has been performed based on the latest DKIM specs
(RFC 4871 or draft-ietf-dkim-base-10) and verification may fail for
older versions.  If you are using Port25's PowerMTA, you need to use
version 3.2r11 or later to get a compatible version of DKIM.




==========================================================
Original Email
==========================================================

Return-Path: <updates@flyawaysimulation.com>
Received: from web3.rbftpnetworks.net (195.224.144.101) by verifier.port25.com id h3rjmm11u9c1 for <check-auth-ryan=rbftpnetworks.com@verifier.port25.com>; Sun, 21 Sep 2014 10:57:47 -0400 (envelope-from <updates@flyawaysimulation.com>)
Authentication-Results: verifier.port25.com; spf=pass smtp.mailfrom=updates@flyawaysimulation.com
Authentication-Results: verifier.port25.com; domainkeys=neutral (message not signed) header.From=updates@flyawaysimulation.com
Authentication-Results: verifier.port25.com; dkim=pass (matches From: updates@flyawaysimulation.com) header.d=flyawaysimulation.com
Authentication-Results: verifier.port25.com; sender-id=pass header.From=updates@flyawaysimulation.com
Received: by web3.rbftpnetworks.net (Postfix, from userid 70)
    id CDAD13E6DCB8; Sun, 21 Sep 2014 15:57:46 +0100 (BST)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/simple;
    d=flyawaysimulation.com; s=mail; t=1411311466;
    bh=PUR9ib4HOSSj9G3jmXSCyzc1LAtqQeyWPSAii67TLd8=;
    h=To:Subject:Date:From:Reply-To:List-Help:List-Unsubscribe:
     List-Subscribe:List-Owner;
    b=skviRyhjPtB8aaRzLKyzkjay3Qk+Z5AOGg4Ue/Dk62SgvP1aZnf3kL1lCSWiwO1rI
     VKYmMzzspbKLxMVrZ0yXO0s4wx5u9EFNw4eJMNh6fKCimiNwEoSGQRkJcjNb7wA9nG
     38/FjbPIkvRyx1+hxgL9QOP3iSGv9w3X0UAFUmmc=
To: check-auth-ryan=rbftpnetworks.com@verifier.port25.com
Subject: Test 123
Received: from host81-138-131-190.in-addr.btopenworld.com [81.138.131.190] by flyawaysimulation.com with HTTP; Sun, 21 Sep 2014 15:57:46 +0100
Date: Sun, 21 Sep 2014 15:57:46 +0100
From: Fly Away Simulation <updates@flyawaysimulation.com>
Reply-To: Fly Away Simulation <updates@flyawaysimulation.com>
Message-ID: <4ecb49f93b720bc688fe3bcdcafed5b0@flyawaysimulation.com>
X-Priority: 3
X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.5 (https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer/)
X-phpList-version: 3.0.7
X-MessageID: 8
X-ListMember: check-auth-ryan=rbftpnetworks.com@verifier.port25.com
Precedence: bulk
Bounces-To: updates@flyawaysimulation.com
List-Help: <https://flyawaysimulation.com/lists/?p=preferences&uid=1e629246241f8e9714134ee8076ad406>
List-Unsubscribe: <https://flyawaysimulation.com/lists/?p=unsubscribe&uid=1e629246241f8e9714134ee8076ad406&jo=1>
List-Subscribe: <https://flyawaysimulation.com/lists/?p=subscribe>
List-Owner: <mailto:abuse@flyawaysimulation.com>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="b1_4ecb49f93b720bc688fe3bcdcafed5b0"

--b1_4ecb49f93b720bc688fe3bcdcafed5b0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

 test 123







 =20



--b1_4ecb49f93b720bc688fe3bcdcafed5b0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<html><head>=0A        <meta content=3D"text/html;charset=3DUTF-8" http-equ=

iv=3D"Content-Type">=0A        <title></title></head><body><p>&nbsp;test 12=

3</p>=0A<img src=3D"https://flyawaysimulation.com/lists/ut.php?u=3D1e629246=

241f8e9714134ee8076ad406&amp;m=3D8" width=3D"1" height=3D"1" border=3D"0" /=

> </body></html>


--b1_4ecb49f93b720bc688fe3bcdcafed5b0--
```

**Same message sent to Gmail:**

```
Delivered-To: ****
Received: by 10.170.191.196 with SMTP id i187csp139225yke;
        Sun, 21 Sep 2014 08:05:20 -0700 (PDT)
X-Received: by 10.194.134.100 with SMTP id pj4mr14856269wjb.72.1411311920538;
        Sun, 21 Sep 2014 08:05:20 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <updates@flyawaysimulation.com>
Received: from web3.rbftpnetworks.net (web3.rbftpnetworks.net. [195.224.144.101])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTP id db4si8324616wib.100.2014.09.21.08.05.20
        for <****>;
        Sun, 21 Sep 2014 08:05:20 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of updates@flyawaysimulation.com designates 195.224.144.101 as permitted sender) client-ip=195.224.144.101;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of updates@flyawaysimulation.com designates 195.224.144.101 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=updates@flyawaysimulation.com;
       dkim=neutral (body hash did not verify) header.i=@
Received: by web3.rbftpnetworks.net (Postfix, from userid 70)
    id E11B93E6E003; Sun, 21 Sep 2014 16:05:18 +0100 (BST)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/simple;
    d=flyawaysimulation.com; s=mail; t=1411311919;
    bh=d40fzjdg7KnEX5wH3Ea2b1ZzoQMu8dzZyP1dYsxaoVc=;
    h=To:Subject:Date:From:Reply-To:List-Help:List-Unsubscribe:
     List-Subscribe:List-Owner;
    b=ub2LA6uRxpsgByD3RRUHqAGhlUu5d1gBgNadBBeaJdDP6pvSL/IX2Lzy6SqG2kGIK
     dU7YnOmI3w0frerJZRldlSAZduKUQqaT0QZHfvUZVJnLihK8EIZ7GkzX+6VVE2Pojm
     J8aVCq8fPOEuCG6mu2QdIUmpqkWO+s8bBYBYR6ro=
To: *****
Subject: Test 123
Received: from host81-138-131-190.in-addr.btopenworld.com [81.138.131.190] by flyawaysimulation.com with HTTP; Sun, 21 Sep 2014 16:05:18 +0100
Date: Sun, 21 Sep 2014 16:05:18 +0100
From: Fly Away Simulation <updates@flyawaysimulation.com>
Reply-To: Fly Away Simulation <updates@flyawaysimulation.com>
Message-ID: <8938d7bccca9e15cd846714ca4a01d04@flyawaysimulation.com>
X-Priority: 3
X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.5 (https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer/)
X-phpList-version: 3.0.7
X-MessageID: 8
X-ListMember: ****
Precedence: bulk
Bounces-To: updates@flyawaysimulation.com
List-Help: <https://flyawaysimulation.com/lists/?p=preferences&uid=58f4e3c38a321901b99d714dd5f54850>
List-Unsubscribe: <https://flyawaysimulation.com/lists/?p=unsubscribe&uid=58f4e3c38a321901b99d714dd5f54850&jo=1>
List-Subscribe: <https://flyawaysimulation.com/lists/?p=subscribe>
List-Owner: <mailto:abuse@flyawaysimulation.com>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="b1_8938d7bccca9e15cd846714ca4a01d04"

--b1_8938d7bccca9e15cd846714ca4a01d04
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

 test 123



 =20


--b1_8938d7bccca9e15cd846714ca4a01d04
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<html><head>=0A        <meta content=3D"text/html;charset=3DUTF-8" http-equ=
iv=3D"Content-Type">=0A        <title></title></head><body><p>&nbsp;test 12=
3</p>=0A<img src=3D"https://flyawaysimulation.com/lists/ut.php?u=3D58f4e3c3=
8a321901b99d714dd5f54850&amp;m=3D8" width=3D"1" height=3D"1" border=3D"0" /=
></body></html>


--b1_8938d7bccca9e15cd846714ca4a01d04--
```

Comment: Code? Error messages? Example of good and bad message headers? What version of PHPMailer?

Comment: Sorry I missed that - sample emails have been included above (what passes/fails).  Also have confirmed the phpMailer version.

Comment: Were you able to find solution to this problem? I am also facing the problem of DKIM fail/neutral when sending email other than text/plain. Tried almost everything that i could find here in stackoverflow and google.

Comment: Are you using PHPList?  The solution was to download the newer version of PHPMailer and overwrite the version PHPList uses.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the exact problem you are describing where [PlainText DKIM=pass] and [HTMLBody DKIM=fail] when sending to Gmail. I'm using `C# MailMessage` and by default the body default character set is "us-ascii", which works fine for Text based emails, but not HTML ones. Default character set for Email Subject is UTF-8, so no need to set again.

When sending a HTML Email, you have to code the following parameter before sending:

```
Mailmessage.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
```

After making this small change, Gmail registers my emails again and I receive a DKIM=pass; when I view the original source. Also these are the relevant headers

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
*followed by block of base64 body text*
```

Perhaps you can mimic the behavior using PHP, and maybe change yours from

```
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
to
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
```

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be two problems:

1. The body canonicalization done by the Port25 verifier is wrong. At the end of the body is
   `> </body></html>`. There the space is wrongly removed. Otherwise the canonicalization is correct.
2. The body hash in the DKIM signature seems to be not the right one for the body received by Port25 (with two different DKIM verifiers I get the body hash `gjpXaqduU+jpM3yh1hPT5jqMSJZjHzi4KqAGlCG0/M8=`). This could be caused by either the message being altered after signing or an error in the signing process.
   Enable `KeepTemporaryFiles` in opendkim to see the body canonicalization done by opendkim and compare it with the one from Port25 (remember the wrongly removed space). Lock also at the source of the sent message if possible and try to see and difference between the send and received body.

**Update**: Comments on the messages with FixCRLF enabled:

phpList seems to generate emails which contains different line endings then CRLFs, which are the only ones allowed in an e-mail. Normally this isn't a problem, but as you can see it can cause problems with DKIM, as different line endings produces different hashes.

**message with "FixCRLF yes" to Port25:**

opendkim seems to have a bug in it's canonicalization algorithm. The line `> </body></html>` in the message to Port25 is wrongly canalized to `></body></html>` (the space is removed). As the verifier in Port25 has the same bug (as it's probably also using opendkim) the signature is wrongly shown as valid by Port25.

This seems not to be the reason for the failure of the message send to gmail, but could cause trouble in the future if messages are send to a receiver which is using a different verifier then opendkim. Best report this problem to them. In the meantime you could remove the space yourself before sending the message.

**message with "FixCRLF yes" to gmail:**

The e-mail received by gmail has less line breaks then the ones received from Port25. So unless the send messages are already different, the message was altered. Enable the "KeepTemporaryFiles" option in opendkim to see the body signed by opendkim.

Comment: With "FixCRLF" set to "yes" in the opendkim config, it passes verification at Port25.  However, the same message with the same configuration fails verification at gmail.  Does this shed any light?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could you please add the report from Port25 to you initial post?

Comment: I have updated the initial post with the passed FixCRLF test message.  I have also included message source for the test sent to Gmail (which failed).  It's passing Port25 and failing at Gmail.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Not a great answer maybe, but I solved this problem by using Amavis instead of opendkim. Make sure you disable opendkim because double signing is not allowed.

This is the manual I used: http://gogs.info/books/debian-mail/chunked/antispam.dkim.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an old question, but I ran into the same problem.
I solved it by splitting the lines in chuncks of 76 characters (per RFC 2045 semantics).
In PHP you can use:
 `$new_string = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));`